# MongoDB: Switch database/collection referenced by a given name on the fly

Tags: mongodb

My application needs only read access to all of its databases. One of those databases (`db_1`) hosts a collection `coll_1` whose entire contents* need to be replaced periodically**.

My goal is to have no or very little effect on read performance for servers currently connected to the database.

Approaches I could think of with so far:

#### 1. renameCollection

Build a temporary collection `coll_tmp`, then use [`renameCollection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/) with `dropTarget: true` to move its contents over to `coll_1`. The downside of this approach is that as far as I can tell, `renameCollection` does not copy indexes, so once the collection is renamed, `coll_1` would need reindexing. While I don't have a good estimate of how long this would take, I would think that query-performance will be significantly affected until reindexing is complete.

#### 2. TTL Index

Instead of straight up replacing, use a [time-to-live index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) to expire documents after the chosen replacement period. Insert new data every time period. This seems like a decent solution to me, except that for our specific application, old data is better than no data. In this scenario, if the cron job to repopulate the database fails for whatever reason, we could potentially be left with an empty `coll_1` which is undesirable. I think this might have a negligible effect, but this solution also requires on-the-fly indexing as every document is inserted.

#### 3. Communicate current database to read-clients

Simply use two different databases (or collections?) and inform connected clients which one is more recent. This solution would allow for finishing indexing the new `coll_1_alt` (and then `coll_1` again) before making it available. I personally dislike the solution since it couples the read clients very closely to the database itself, and of course communication channels are always imperfect.

#### 4. copyDatabase

Use [copyDatabase](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/copy-databases-between-instances/) to rename (designate) an alternate database `db_tmp` to `db_1`.`db_tmp` would also have a collection `coll_1`. Once reindexing is complete on `db_tmp.coll_1`, `copyDatabase` could be used to simply rename `db_tmp` to `db_1`. It seems that this would require droppping `db_1` before renaming, leaving a window in which data won't be accessible.

Ideally (and naively), I'd just set `db_1` to be something akin to a `symlink`, switching to the most current database as needed.

Anyone has good suggestions on how to achieve the desired effect?

<sub>*There are about 10 million documents in `coll_1`.</sub>

<sub>** The current plan is to replace the collection once every 24 hours. The replacement interval might get as low as once every 30 minutes, but not lower.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you point out in option 4 you will also have with option 1. dropTarget will also mean that the collection is not available.

Another alternative could be to just have both the old and the new data in the same collection, and use a "version ID" that you then still have to communicate to your clients to do a query on. That at least stops you from having to do reindexing like you pointed out for option 1.

I think your best bet is actually option 3, and it's the most equivalent to changing a symlink, except it is on the client side.

Comment: I think I'll probably go with option number 3 (unless someone comes up with a solution we haven't thought of), although I also like the idea of version IDs.